# How to dynamically set parameter on ng-click with variable from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to grab the `{{date | date:'dd'}}` expression in my label and insert it as a method parameter on my `ng-click`. The problem is that I get an `undefined is not a function` error when I try this. The `{{}}` expression populates as it should, but it looks like `date` going into the `ng-click` is acting like some undefined variable. I'm not sure how to resolve this, any help would be appreciated.

```
<div ng-controller="methodController">
    <div class="btn-group" data-ng-repeat="date in dates">
        <label data-ng-click="method(date | date:'dd')">{{date | date:'dd'}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried:

`ng-click="method(date)`
`ng-click="method({{date | date:'dd'}})`

In Angular, I use the below method to create my array of dates.

```
$scope.dates = [];

for (var i = -3; i <= 3; i++) {
    var today = new Date();
    $scope.dates.push(today.setDate(today.getDate() + i));
}
```

And my method is defined as such within the `methodController`:

```
$scope.method = function (date) {
//code guts
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off the others. The $filter function seems to be the answer. But filters it inside the controller logic rather than in the method in the view. Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GkoRgggYWUV83KSM29oe?p=preview).

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Title</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="date in dates" 
        ng-click="alert(date)" 
        ng-class="{{date | date:'dd'}}">click here: {{date | date:'dd'}} </li>
 </ul> 

  <script>

angular.module('plunker')
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
   $scope.dates = [];
    $scope.newDate = new Date();
    var today = $scope.newDate

    for(i = -3; i < 0; i++) {
     $scope.dates.push(today.setDate(today.getDate() + i));
    } 

    $scope.alert = function(a) {
    var b = $filter('date')(a, 'dd');
    alert(b);  
  };

});
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: yep cheers - no problem. The Angularjs team referenced it a lot so I tried it and like the ui/features better than the others.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to where your `method` is defined.

So, I suggest the following design to make things more connected

**Define method inside your controller as a property of `$scope` object as follows**

```
$scope.method = function(date)
{
 //your method logic here
}
```

**Then invoke the method in the markup as follows**

```
<div ng-controller="YourController as c" />
...
<div class="btn-group" ng-repeat="date in dates">
    <label ng-click="c.method(date)">{{date | date:'dd'}}</label>
</div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: I added more info to my question. From the looks of it, the only thing I was missing from your answer is the controller alias. I set a `console.log(date)` in the method and now it seems the `ng-click` isn't even hitting the method.

Comment: I tried it and it worked with me. Not sure what was wrong with you. However, I see you already got a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question:

You want to pass the filtered `date` to your method (which is defined inside the controller).

To do that you could:

1. define the filter in your controller

   `app.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $filter) {
       $scope.dateFilter = $filter('date');
   });`
2. invoke it in your view

   `ng-click="method(dateFilter(date, 'dd'))"`

Comment: Please add some explanation of how this would solve the problem. See [answer] for tips on how to make a great answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan hope it's now better